# Moved from Windows server 2000 to 2008 now classic ASP catalog queries not working correctly

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2, indexing-service

This one is driving me crazy.

Replaced our old Windows 2000 web server with a Windows 2008 one which means moving to IIS7.

Now the move went smoothly except for the search catalogs we had set up on the old machine.

I added the Indexing Service and created the catalog for our website.

However, now the classic ASP page that queries the catalog is behaving strangely.

Specifically, the "vpath" and "doctitle" are blank.  Other fields are being returned correctly like "characterization" and "rank" but others are not.

And the most annoying part is anytime I make a change to the search results page I get this error:

`The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`

...and I have to wait a couple of seconds before retrying.  And then the page will come up fine.  Very bizarre.

Anyway, here's the classic ASP code:

```
Set objQuery = Server.CreateObject("ixsso.Query")
With objQuery
      .Catalog = "Website"
      .Columns = "doctitle, vpath, size, characterization, rank"
      .SortBy = "rank[d], doctitle"
      .MaxRecords = 50
End With
objQuery.Query = "(#filename *.asp) AND (@contents " & Request.Form("searchterms") & ")"
Set rsSystem = objQuery.CreateRecordset("nonsequential")
Do Until rsSystem.EOF
       %><dt><a href="<% = rsSystem("vpath") %>"><% = rsSystem("doctitle") %></a></dt>
         <dd><% = rsSystem("characterization") %>...</dd><%
       rsSystem.MoveNext
Loop
```

Anyone else experience this?

Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the relevant bit of the IIS log please?

Comment: Are the old and the new server both x86 or x64? There are a lot of things to take into account migrating if the OS changes from 32 bit to 64 bit.

Comment: Any update on this one ? I guess I have a similar error by migrating a server from WS2K to WS2008 my OLEDB connection are no longer working even if the credentials are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should do is to Enable IIS's detailed errors, to indicate which line of code is causing this error specifically.

Read the following page's "2) Enable IIS7 detailed errors" section, and give it a try. I hope it will help you some.

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/26/Troubleshoot-IIS7-errors-like-a-pro.aspx